# Express cookie-parser is not written on browser

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I am using express and cookie-parser on my nodejs rest server. 
After the cookie was sent, I can see in the network: 
Set-Cookie:xxxx=xxxxxxxxxxx; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 29 Dec 2015 18:14:06 GMT; HttpOnly
But there is nothing in my Browser cookie.
Is it because I'm using localhost?

```

```
const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());


app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  let email = req.body.email;
  let pass = req.body.password;
  (new User()).login(email, pass)
  .then(response => {
    if (response) {
      res.cookie('mid', email, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), httpOnly: true })
      .send('ok');
    } else {
      res.status(503).end();
    }
  });
});
```

```

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing, or is it that you're setting the cookie to httpOnly, and therefore the client has no access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using React + Relay and I need to add a

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('/graphql', {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  })
);
```

To make it work.